# Small regex question in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying everything in a string BUT a certain pattern.

My pattern is:

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/D";
```

And I want to do the following:

```
$string = preg_replace(anything but $pattern, "", $string);
```

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the caret "**^**" in the character class to say you don't want these characters.

```
$pattern = "/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/D";
```

**Explanation**

> ^ Negates the character class, causing it to match a single character not listed in the character class. (Specifies a caret if placed anywhere except after the opening [)

[Source, regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: Thanks! regex is a hell for a new beginner :/

Comment: Regular expressions are easy, you just need to keep on practicing :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = /^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$/D
```

The `^` between the square brackets, `[` and `]`, will make the group match all not of them. This will match from beginning of string to end, I'm not sure wether you need that too.

```
$pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+?"
```

Would work matching all the parts of the string which does not get matched by the other pattern.